# Cannot run SSR script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering

I have a completed React app that I'm trying to render it server-side using node and express. Problem is no matter what I try, the script I made won't run. Any help would be appreciated

I have one folder called server outside of src folder where the react stuff is, with 2 js files in it:

server/index.js file:

```
require('ignore-styles');
require('@babel/polyfill');

require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
});

require('./server');
```

server/server.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

import App from '../src/App'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

const app = express()

app.use('^/$', (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(500).send('Some error happened')
    }
    return res.send(data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`))
  })
})

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App launched on ${PORT}`)
})
```

And finally the script in package.json that runs it (ssr):

```
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "ssr": "babel-node index.js"
```

The whole react app is written in typescript which might be causing the issue, but i havent found a solution to it yet.

When i run the script i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjQ8C.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in src/App? This is a bit hard to debug as is. Can you provide a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: Its the entry point for the react app, contains the routes etc, and it has .tsx extension